# Webpage alert message on add cart button

Tags: javascript, php, html, shopping-cart

I would like to display an alert message in my webpage in case the size or colour radio button was not selected into the form. Can anybody help me? I tried something but did not worked. See below my code:

```
<div id="Form"><form method="POST" autocomplete="off" title="Product">     
  <input name="title" type="hidden" id="title" value="0">
  <br>
  <p name="cor">
    <strong>
    <label><br>Color:</strong></span><br>
    </label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="cor" value="white" id="cor_0">
      White</label></p>
    <p name="Size">
    <label><br>Size:<br></label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="size" value="22" id="22" onclick="setShoppingCartUrl(this)">
      M</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="size" value="23" id="23"     onclick="setShoppingCartUrl(this)">
      G</label>
    </strong></p>
  <p><br></p>
<script>
 baseurl = 'cart2.php?add=';
function setShoppingCartUrl(e) {
document.getElementById('shoppingcart').href=baseurl+e.value
}
</script></div>
<div><script>
function setShoppingCartindexUrl()
if (value < 20) {
    alert('<?php echo "Please select your size"; ?>');
         }
    else {
    href="cart2.php?add=."
    }   </script>
<a id="shoppingcart" onclick="setShoppingCartindexUrl()" target="_self"><img      src="images/carrinho01.jpg" alt="noiva em detalhes" width="100%" height="100%"       align="rigth" margin-right="8%"/></a>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: why not make them required fields and let the browser do the work?

Comment: Why do you have PHP echoing a static string? `alert('<?php echo "Please select your size"; ?>');` shouldn't be using PHP.

Comment: Hi Devlin, I am seeing cases that the customer do not know how to proceed. It seems easy to us but for some users could be not so obvious. That is why I am intend to give them the alert message. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Hi Styphon, You are right, I do not know how to display this alert. I give a guess and of course this did not worked at all. I had tried some other guess with no success also but yes, you understand where I need help. Do you have any code suggestion?

Comment: Add to your `input`s the `required` attribute you will force users to compile them. A little warning text will automatically appear. Basic but funcionally validation. If you want advanced control in validation `input`s consider to handle the form submit through javascript before send it to the server.

Comment: Hello Stuff_H4pp3nz, thank you for the "required" suggestion. I am sure it would work for a submit input but did not worked in this case I guess because I am not using the submit input but I am using href to relate the product in my php cart (href="cart2.php?add=."). Any other suggestion in this case?

Comment: what I'm trying to say is to make your fields required.  the browser will alert your users if they try to submit without giving a value to required fields.  for example:  `<input required type="radio" name="size" value="22" id="22" >`

Comment: Yes Devlin, I understand exactly what you mean but in my case It did not worked because I am not using a button to send a form but a link to add in my cart.php page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some researches I founded exactly what I need, so below my code after implementation...

```
<script>
function validateForm() {
var x = document.forms["myForm"]["size"].value;
if (x == null || x == "") {
    alert("Querida cliente, favor selecionar o tamanho desejado antes de adicionar ao carrinho.");
    return false;
}
else {
        href="cart2.php?add=."
    }}
</script>
<a id="shoppingcart" onclick="validateForm()" target="_self"><img src="images/carrinho01.jpg" alt="noiva em detalhes" width="100%" height="100%" align="rigth" margin-right="8%"/></a>
```